# Prevent logged in user from accessing login route with Flask-Login

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I'm using Flask-Login and want to prevent logged in users from going to certain pages, such as `/login`.  Is there an opposite of `@login_required`, like `@logout_required`?

Answer (score 3):

Sure, there is a `current_user` proxy you can use, so within a view route you could just do:

```
if current_user.is_authenticated:
    return redirect(url_for('already_logged_in'))  ## or whatever.
```